# ajax request one by one

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need a function that click one link, send ajax request to 2 pages one by one.

first send data to `page1.php`, when finish page1's work, back the data to the main page, then send data to `page2.php` do another ajax process and return data to the main page.

I write `page2.php` Request in `page1.php`  `document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;`, but this will only return the `page2's` data and miss back the data from `page1.php`

in `firebug` , consule:

```
page1.php (always show loading.gif)
page2.php 200 OK 2199ms
```

how to do the ajax one by one well? Thanks.

```
function myajax(text) {
      var HttPRequest = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
            HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
         }
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
         try {
            HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e) {
            try {
               HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
         }
      } 
      if (!HttPRequest) {
         alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
         return false;
      }
        var url = 'page1.php';
        var pmeters = "text=" + text;
        HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);
        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttPRequest.send(pmeters);
        HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {

             if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) 
              {
               document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;

               var url = 'page2.php';
                    var pmeters = "text=" + text;
                    HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);
                    HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    HttPRequest.send(pmeters);
                    HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
                    {

                         if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) 
                          {
                           document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;
                          }
                    }
              }
        }
   }
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use a framework like JQuery for AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to do it.

1. Use Ajax in Synchronous mode, so the code will wait until you get results from page1
2. Call the Ajax method for Page2 only at the response of Page1

Option 2 is better since it work in Asynchronous mode.

Here is a pseudo code:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open( ..)
 xhr.onreadstatechange = function() {
      // handle page1 response

      // do page2 reauest
      var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr2.open( ... )
      xhr2.onreadystatechange =  function() {
        // handle page2 response

      }
      xhr2.send(null);
 }
 xhr.send(null);
```